# .Net Core Console App not running in Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, console-application

My .Net Core 2.1 Console App works fine when debugging in Visual Studio. Logs are posting fine to Elastic Search and visible in Kabana. When I try and deploy this app in a container I am not getting any logs posted to ES. Also I can see no Docker logs when I type `docker logs <container-id>` - I have included my Program Class and Docker file below. I am new to Docker, is there anything obvious that I have missed? Do I need to open some ports or something? Is it OK using an `appsettings.json` file in Docker like this? Could this be causing issues?

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using RizbotCore.BitmexTrader.Controllers;
using RizbotCore.BitmexTrader.Services;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch;

namespace RizbotCore.BitmexTrader
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //setup our DI
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging()
                .AddSingleton<ITraderMain, TraderMain>()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            // Adding JSON file into IConfiguration.
            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                 .Build();

            // Read configuration
            var appSettings = config.GetSection("ElasticConfiguration");
            string esURL = appSettings["ES_URL"];

            // Set up Logging
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .MinimumLevel.Debug()
             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
             .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(esURL))  
             {
                 AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
             })
             .CreateLogger();

            Log.Information("Starting Up...");

            // Start Main Manager
            var traderMain = serviceProvider.GetService<ITraderMain>();
            await traderMain.Start(serviceProvider);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Docker file:

```
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY RizbotCore.Trader/RizbotCore.BitmexTrader.csproj RizbotCore.Trader/
COPY RizBotCore.DAL/RizBotCore.DAL.csproj RizBotCore.DAL/
RUN dotnet restore "RizbotCore.Trader/RizbotCore.BitmexTrader.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RizbotCore.Trader"
RUN dotnet build "RizbotCore.BitmexTrader.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RizbotCore.BitmexTrader.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RizbotCore.BitmexTrader.dll"]
```

Comment: Try running your container without detaching it from your console (i.e. don't specify the `-d` flag on the `docker run` command). Usually that helps me see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the required ports in the dockerfile for all the communications you need i.e. `EXPOSE 80`. Then when performing `docker run` over the image you just created out of the dockerfile, you will need to map the exposed ports outside i.e. `docker run -p 80:80 <yourImageName>`